# Rails 4 activerecord group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an Order table and each order has a SOURCE and ORDER TOTAL. The source is basically were the order came from (Phone, Web, Ebay and so on).

I would like you get all orders and display them grouped by SOURCE and show the Total amount for each SOURCE.

- Phone Orders - $1200.293
- Web Orders - $1537.30
- Ebay Orders - $567.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Order.group(:source).sum(:order_total)
```

More about [sum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum) and [group](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-group)